# Docker fails to start container in detached mode

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I have a Google VM that i am trying to start a container, that will start up a web server.

Since i want to be able to do other things with my terminal, i tried starting the container in detached mode.

This is what i typed:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 5001:5001 -v $(pwd):/mnt/translation -w="/mnt/translation" -e "TERM=xterm-color" f_translate
```

After this, i get back a string

```
9f8cc86f1e4a262bff8ff4f40f1a9036c686472b0ec3fded84980a60d26f6980
```

However, i couldn't connect to the server with `docker exec`.

I typed `docker ps`, to see all running containers, but there are none running.

EDIT:
This is the result of the `docker ps -a`:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND       CREATED          STATUS                      PORTS     NAMES
9f8cc86f1e4a   f_translate    "/bin/bash"   28 minutes ago   Exited (0) 28 minutes ago             reverent_sinouss
i
faeec783edce   f_translate    "/bin/bash"   37 minutes ago   Exited (0) 37 minutes ago             adoring_chaum
1b96a5117aef   f_translate    "/bin/bash"   25 hours ago     Exited (129) 24 hours ago             xenodochial_noet
her
b364de5733b9   f_translate    "/bin/bash"   41 hours ago     Created                               nice_lumiere
5b042e459548   f_translate    "/bin/bash"   41 hours ago     Exited (0) 41 hours ago               hardcore_elbakya
n
ea97b56d6822   f_translate    "/bin/bash"   42 hours ago     Created                               practical_lumier
e
2392c2b074a1   f_translate    "/bin/bash"   42 hours ago     Created                               hardcore_easley
e24c579f3094   f_translate    "/bin/bash"   42 hours ago     Created                               inspiring_merkle
3e4e412c551b   f_translate    "/bin/bash"   42 hours ago     Created                               crazy_engelbart
8c198931c560   f_translate    "/bin/bash"   42 hours ago     Exited (0) 41 hours ago               hardcore_cannon
67c5ad80b074   f_translate    "/bin/bash"   42 hours ago     Exited (0) 42 hours ago               dreamy_margulis
b2b8773a9d77   a2f276018a81   "/bin/bash"   42 hours ago     Exited (127) 42 hours ago             jolly_greider
2c3c74ee073c   a2f276018a81   "/bin/bash"   42 hours ago     Exited (0) 42 hours ago               pensive_chandras
ekhar
8563a35a96a7   cq_image       "/bin/bash"   47 hours ago     Exited (127) 46 hours ago             gallant_rubin
44431d47308c   cq_image       "/bin/bash"   2 days ago       Exited (129) 2 days ago               peaceful_tesla
```

When i type `docker logs 9f8cc86f1e4a262bff8ff4f40f1a9036c686472b0ec3fded84980a60d26f6980`, i get nothing back.

Comment: Try to run `docker ps -a` to check if the container crashed. Check out `docker logs 9f8cc86f1e4a262bff8ff4f40f1a9036c686472b0ec3fded84980a60d26f6980` to see what happened.

Comment: Yes could you add logs?

Comment: Thank you guys. I updated the question with everything you ask.

Comment: If you ran this process without Docker, how would you get a shell inside the process?  (Why is `docker exec` critical to your workflow?)

Answer (score 2):

You're run the container only with the bash command. This command returns exit code 0 immediately after the run. Then container finishing the work.
You have to run the container with some process that not returns the exit code right after a run.
This is a normal behavior that container finishing work when the job is finished with the success or with the error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Though i am not sure exactly what you mean with the "i have run the container only with the bash command". Do i need to change something in the command that starts the container in a detached mode?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if there is a need to explain what containers do:

Containers have been designed to do one job. You tell them which command to execute and they will do that until it is done. Usually this is specified within a `Dockerfile`, in there you can define `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` to tell the container what to do when starting up. The container will then do that particular job until its done and then shut down.

And that's the case with your container. Your container executes the command `/bin/bash` as can be seen in the `COMMAND` column of the `docker ps -a` output.
So it actually is doing what it is supposed to do. It simply is executing the bash and since the command finished at that point it is shutting down, therefore you cannot connect to it anymore.

To be able to exec into a container it must be up and running, to do so you will have to change the entrypoint of your container. You can either do so by building a new image via a `Dockerfile` or you can overwrite it on the fly with the `docker run` command.
For debugging purposes, especially when wanting to exec into the container manually, you are most likely going to choose a command that does nothing but runs forever, perhaps something like `sleep infinity`.

**TL;DR**

With `docker run` after mentioning the image name you can define which command the container shall execute when starting up.
Execute the following command to ensure that your container does not exit immediately:

```sh
sudo docker run -d -p 5001:5001 -v $(pwd):/mnt/translation -w="/mnt/translation" -e "TERM=xterm-color" f_translate /bin/sh -c sleep infinity
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried your code, but it exhibits the same behaviour. It exits immediately.